# gnus "fancy" hyperlinks, bullet points, etc

Tags: gnus, message

Is there a way to get more formatting options from a gnus message buffer when composing a mail? I'd like to do hyperlinks of the style common in markdown or org-mode, viz:

```
[[example link][http://www.example.com]]
[example link](http://www.example.com)
```

Similarly, I'm wondering if there's a way to enable more "fancy" options such as bullet points, blockquotes, etc. I found [org-gnus.el](http://orgmode.org/w/?p=org-mode.git;a=blob_plain;f=lisp/org-gnus.el;hb=HEAD), but I'm too much of a newbie to understand what it does.

-Steven

Comment: `org-gnus.el` is for linking to messages via `org-capture`.  For instance, if capture a appointment from a gnus buffer it will save a link to mail under that heading.

Comment: I came here to ask this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe [`org-mime.el`](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-mime.html) by **Eric Schulte**.

```
;; WYSWYG, html mime composition using org-mode
;;
;; For mail composed using the orgstruct-mode minor mode, this
;; provides a function for converting all or part of your mail buffer
;; to embedded html as exported by org-mode.  Call `org-mime-htmlize'
;; in a message buffer to convert either the active region or the
;; entire buffer to html.
;;
;; Similarly the `org-mime-org-buffer-htmlize' function can be called
;; from within an org-mode buffer to convert the buffer to html, and
;; package the results into an email handling with appropriate MIME
;; encoding.
```

Comment: Yes, this is better for my purposes than `muse-message`. I am already familiar with org syntax, so I don't have to learn anything new. Also, org-mode's WYSIWYG method of displaying links looks cleaner onscreen, which means less likelihood of me making a mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I located a package called [muse-message](https://github.com/jwiegley/muse/blob/master/experimental/muse-message.el), which does exactly what I was hoping for. I have not ever used [Muse](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs-muse/), but it's a markup system similar to markdown.

Muse-message allows for using Muse markup, and then `M-x muse-message-markup` turns the message buffer into a multipart MIME message with an HTML component.